# How to access DataGridView from another class in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my program have Form8 and Class named as Book.In Form8 there has a DataGridView and i need to access that DataGridView from Book class.Can anyone explain how to do it?I did following things in my book

```
public void searchBook(string valueToSearch)
    {

        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        con.mysqlconnection();
        con.sqlquery("select * from TBL_Book where CONCAT(ISBN_No,BookName,Author,Publisher,CategoryID,ReOrderLevel)like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'");
        con.dataread();
        con.datatable();
        con.table.Load(con.datareader);
        Form8 f8 = new Form8();
        f8.DGV.DataSource = con.table;
    }
```

and following things in Form8

```
 public Form8()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DGV = dataGridView1;
    }
 public DataGridView DGV { get; set; }
```

Comment: It looks like you already are accessing the `DataGridView` in your code.  But you forgot to *show* the form.  Or do you already have a form open and you want to use *that* form instead of an entirely new one?  If that's the case then you would need to pass a reference to the form you want into that method, just like you already pass a string into that method.

Comment: "i need to access that DataGridView from Book class". No, you don't, absolutely not. Let the code return the data source and bind in your UI code.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would remove the lines related to Form8 variable from the data access class (I believe its the Book class). You can return a DataTable from the searchBook() and bind it in the Form8.

```
public DataTable searchBook(string valueToSearch)
{

    DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
    con.mysqlconnection();
    con.sqlquery("select * from TBL_Book where CONCAT(ISBN_No,BookName,Author,Publisher,CategoryID,ReOrderLevel)like '%" + valueToSearch + "%'");
    con.dataread();
    con.datatable();
    con.table.Load(con.datareader);

    return con.table;
}


public Form8()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1;
}

void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Book b = new Book();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = b.searchBook("Text To Search");
}
```